# Is it possible to use Gitlab as an oauth provider?

Tags: oauth-2.0, gitlab

I know that it is possible to [log into Gitlab with external providers](https://cm-gitlab.stanford.edu/help/api/oauth2.md) such as Github.
However, I was wondering if Gitlab's oauth can be used to authenticate users to my application?

Is there an oauth endpoint that I can use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be possible since the suggestion "[Oauth system for third party application](http://feedback.gitlab.com/forums/176466-general/suggestions/6549190-oauth-system-for-third-party-application)" seems completed with [GitLab 7.7](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/de6256ee67f8b5a8623d8a4c510f5181d0d492db/CHANGELOG#L10) ([which is to be released](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/releases))

> > It would be powerful to have an oauth authentication system with application management like Github.
> >
> > If this feature appear on Gitlab, developers would be able to create many third party applications like Travis-CI or Scrutinizer who can Interact directly with a "Gitlab Connect" system, same as Github or Bitbucket.
> >
> > We should manage authorization scope too (profile view / edit, group access, projects access etc...).
>
> GitLab team (Admin, Gitlab) responded  ·  Dec 22, 2014
>
> Completed In GitLab 7.7

See the [diff between GitLab 7.6 and 7.7](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/compare/7-6-stable...master) and:

- [commit ed932d8](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/commit/ed932d82db3bf9d3e557c289ed2ccfbc99ab5083)
- [commit f9ece12](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/commit/f9ece12e872e9bf748f4daebfba88c341d4046f5)

---

*February 2016 edit, complementary links:*

- [GitLab as OAuth2 authentication service provider](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/integration/oauth_provider.html)
- [GitLab as an OAuth2 client](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/api/oauth2.html#gitlab-as-an-oauth2-client)
- [Doorkeeper](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper), what GitLab uses to implement OAuth

---

Note: with [GitLab 13.11](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/04/22/gitlab-13-11-released/#register-oauth-applications-at-the-group-level) (April 2021)

> ### Register OAuth applications at the group level
>
> Group owners can now register OAuth applications for a group.
>
> Previously, OAuth applications could only be registered by individual users or at the instance level.
>
> Making this functionality available at the group level reduces the administrative burden for instance administrators and removes the dependency on individual users for the configuration of OAuth applications.
>
> Thanks to the amazing work from GitLab contributor Jonas Wälter from Siemens, this feature is now available in 13.11.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/oauth_provider.html#group-owned-applications) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/16227).

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not. Currently the only supported scope is `api` which gives the authentication client full access to everything in the user's name. See https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/22323 to track progress.