# How to Login using Gitlab?

Tags: gitlab

I want to implement authentication system in my web application using `Gitlab`.

That is, users can login to my application using `Gitlab's` username and password. How can I achieve this?

Comment: check the [gitlab oauth service](http://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/oauth_provider.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is is possible to use Gitlab as an oauth provider](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27815931/is-is-possible-to-use-gitlab-as-an-oauth-provider)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking to use Gitlab as the authentication provider for your application.

The [GitLab as OAuth2 authentication service provider](http://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/oauth_provider.html) documentation should get you started.

From the documentation:

> For example, you can allow users to sign in to your application with their GitLab.com account

Comment: Thank you so much. I was able to get the keys. But can you provide me some direction regarding connecting my application with Gitlab? And the use of the keys? Are there any straightforward documentation that covers each step?

Comment: I don't know Gitlab that well, you should be able to use pretty much any compliant OAuth library to connect. Google for `[your language of choice here] oauth client library`. The client library would probably have a sample of getting OAuth working.